# Find a match in workbook using Excel VBA: run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to create a macro which searches for the word "Routing" in all sheets of my active workbook.

When it detects the first occurrence in one of my sheets of my workbook, I want my macro to select the related cell on the corresponding sheet.

My macro returns the error message:

> run-time error 1004: activate method of range class failed…

It seems this line of code generates the issue: `Loc.Activate`

```
Sub FindAndExecuteRouting()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim Loc As Range
For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With Sh.UsedRange
        Set Loc = .Cells.Find(What:="Routing")
        If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
            Loc.Activate
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `Activate` a `Range` unless it's on the `ActiveSheet`.

So you'd have to do `Sh.Activate` before you can do `Loc.Activate`. Note that normally you do not want to [Activate a cell you already have a reference to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513), but when **the goal** is to select a cell so that the user can see the selection box around a specific cell... well, that's one of the very few legit use cases for `Worksheet.Activate` =)

```
Public Sub FindAndExecuteRouting()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Dim Loc As Range
    For Each Sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Sh.UsedRange
            Set Loc = .Find(What:="Routing")
            If Not Loc Is Nothing Then
                Sh.Activate
                Loc.Activate
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Note the `Exit Sub`: you want to stop looping (`Exit For` would work as well) once you've found one, otherwise you'll just successively select every result very quickly, and only the last one will end up selected.

Consider using an [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) to help keep indentation consistent!